# What is Christian scholars' take on the `chicken-or-egg-first' riddle?

Tags: genesis, non-denominational

We read in Gen 1: 20-21 (NRSVCE):

> And God said, “Let the waters bring forth swarms of living creatures, and **let birds fly above the earth across the dome of the sky.**” So God created the great sea monsters and every living creature that moves, of every kind, with which the waters swarm, and every winged bird of every kind.

That shows that birds were intended to fly, at the time of their creation. But now, we have the chicken which cannot fly above a certain level. According to entries in the wikipedia, The chicken (Gallus domesticus) is a domesticated subspecies of the red junglefowl.The red junglefowl (Gallus gallus) is a tropical bird in the family Phasianidae.  Evidence from the molecular level derived from whole-genome sequencing revealed that the chicken was domesticated from red junglefowl about 8,000 years ago. The grey junglefowl, Sri Lankan junglefowl and green junglefowl  also contributed genetic material to the gene pool of the chicken.

The riddle "Which came first: the chicken or the egg?" has been troubling mankind since long, especially against the backdrop of theory of evolution. Going by Gen 1:20-21, one is inclined to think that God did not create chicken in the form we have it today. So, there is a chance that the egg came first, followed by chicken!

My question therefore is: What is Christian scholars' take on the `chicken-or-egg-fist'  riddle in the context of Genesis 1:20-21 and history of aviculture? Inputs from any denomination are welcome.

Comment: "Chicken or egg" is just a riddle. It has nothing to do with Christianity. It's not even a serious question for actual philosophers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Which Came First—The Chicken or the Egg?**

What would creationists believe? On Day Five of Creation Week, God created “every winged bird according to its kind” (Genesis 1:21). God created mature birds with the ability to reproduce. So the bird was first, ready to lay eggs.

God created mature birds with the ability to reproduce. So the bird was first, ready to lay eggs.

While we know that birds came first, that fails to address the specific question about domesticated chickens. Is it possible to determine the chicken’s ancestor that was created on Day Five? Classification research is a very young field, but chickens happen to be one of the creatures that creationists have investigated to identify the original parent kinds.

Although you desire to know what is the Christian scholars' take on the `chicken-or-egg-first' riddle, it would seem there is no real take on this particular riddle.

We do know that  Aristotle, the philosopher was credited as the first to study formal logic, wondered which came first. Chickens come from eggs, and eggs come from chickens. How can one come before the other? What came first, the chicken or the egg?

> The question represents an ancient folk paradox addressing the problem of origins and first cause. Aristotle, writing in the fourth century BCE, concluded that this was an infinite sequence, with no true origin.[3] Plutarch, writing four centuries later, specifically highlighted this question as bearing on a "great and weighty problem (whether the world had a beginning)". In the fifth century CE, Macrobius wrote that while the question seemed trivial, it "should be regarded as one of importance".
>
> By the end of the 16th century, the well-known question seemed to have been regarded as settled in the Christian world, based on the origin story of the Bible. In describing the creation of animals, it allows for a first chicken that did not come from an egg. However, later enlightenment philosophers began to question this solution. Carlo Dati in the mid 17th-century published an erudite satire on the subject. - [Chicken or the egg](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_or_the_egg)

Even Christian scholars and philosophers have to go with science in order to possibly solve this riddle.

> As for chickens, they came into being much later. They are domesticated animals, so evolved as the result of humans purposefully selecting the least aggressive wild birds and letting them breed. This seems to have happened in several places independently, starting around 10,000 years ago.
>
> The wild ancestor of chickens is generally agreed to be a tropical bird still living in the forests of Southeast Asia called the red junglefowl –  with other junglefowl species possibly adding to the genetic mix. From these origins, humans have carried chickens around the world over the past two millennia or more.
>
> So, eggs dramatically predate chickens. But to be fair to the spirit of the riddle, we should also consider whether a chicken’s egg predates a chicken. As humans consistently chose the tamest red junglefowls and bred them together, the genetic makeup of the resulting birds will have shifted. At some stage during this domestication process the red junglefowl (Gallus gallus) evolved into a new subspecies, Gallus gallus domesticus, AKA the chicken.
>
> In practice, it is impossible to pinpoint the moment when this happened. But in theory, at some point two junglefowl bred and their offspring was genetically different enough from the species of its parents to be classified as a chicken. This chicken would have developed within a junglefowl egg and only produced the very first chicken’s egg on reaching maturity. Looked at this way, the chicken came first. - [Which came first, the chicken or the egg?](https://www.newscientist.com/question/came-first-chicken-egg/)

We may never solve this conundrum!

> **Scientific resolutions**
>
> Although the question is typically used metaphorically, evolutionary biology provides literal answers, made possible by the Darwinian principle that species evolve over time, and thus that chickens had ancestors that were not chickens, similar to a view expressed by the Greek philosopher Anaximander when addressing the paradox.
>
> If the question refers to eggs in general, the egg came first. The first amniote egg—that is, a hard-shelled egg that could be laid on land, rather than remaining in water like the eggs of fish or amphibians—appeared around 312 million years ago. In contrast, chickens are domesticated descendants of red junglefowl and probably arose little more than eight thousand years ago, at most.
>
> If the question refers to chicken eggs specifically, the answer is still the egg,nbut the explanation is more complicated. The process by which the chicken arose through the interbreeding and domestication of multiple species of wild jungle fowl is poorly understood, and the point at which this evolving organism became a chicken is a somewhat arbitrary distinction. Whatever criteria one chooses, an animal nearly identical to the modern chicken (i.e., a proto-chicken) laid a fertilized egg that had DNA making it a modern chicken due to mutations in the mother's ovum, the father's sperm, or the fertilized zygote.
>
> It has been suggested that the actions of a protein found in modern chicken eggs may make the answer different. In the uterus, chickens produce ovocleidin-17 (OC-17), which causes the formation of the thickened calcium carbonate shell around their eggs. Because OC-17 is expressed by the hen and not the egg, the bird in which the protein first arose, though having hatched from a non-reinforced egg, would then have laid the first egg having such a reinforced shell: the chicken would have preceded this first 'modern' chicken egg.bHowever, the presence of OC-17 or a homolog in other species, such as turkeys and finches suggests that such eggshell-reinforcing proteins are common to all birds, and thus long predate the first chickens. - [Chicken or the egg](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_or_the_egg)

I do not believe that Christian scholars have an opinion on this issue one way or another. It is a riddle and a conundrum!